# lighttpd: symlink as document root

Tags: lighttpd

Is it possible to use a symlink as document root for lighttpd?

I tried it with:

`ln -s ./www-1 ./doc-root`

And then:

`server.document-root = var.CWD +  "/doc-root"`

But it appears that lighttpd just resolves the symlink and uses that as document root instead.

Essentially I want to switch between two document roots without patching the current config, restarting or spawning another instance of lighttpd.

Sadly `mod_alias` shows the same behavior:

`alias.url = ( "/" => var.CWD + "/doc-root" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lighttpd supports symlinks.

You are messing yourself up by using `var.CWD`, which uses `getcwd()` to determine the current working directory.  This resolution of the current working directory resoves symlinks when determining the current working directory.

Use `var.mysymlinkroot` instead of var.CWD, and define `var.mysymlinkroot` to be the path to the symlink.

Comment: Okay this works for static files but doesn't with PHP-CGI, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Well with PHP-CGI I mean the fastcgi version.

Comment: Never mind, I found a solution which works quite well :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you share with the class? I'm having a similar issue